# Рow to set elements with . image behavior?

Tags: javascript

document.querySelector ('. image'); сhoose only first element

but i need everything (width class image)
how to do?

`enter code here` https://jsfiddle.net/4ubo2y71/

Comment: maybe [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: set first line in js - const image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

Comment: but doesn't work

Comment: it returns an array instead of a single element. loop it.

Comment: I understand
but i need a handler on them
   in js 34 and 39 lines

Comment: loop the array and `addEventListener` on every element within the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: set first line in js - const image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');